# Randomly getting "this site cannot be reached" error

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools

My website continually gets the "this site cannot be reached" error at random when I'm clicking through my URLs.

When I click a link on my website the "this site cannot be reached" page pops up for less than a second and then the page loads.

It doesn't happen all the time but it does happen more than I would like.

I have no idea what would cause this at random, any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error I'm refering to.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser. Can you reproduce it in another browser on the same machine?

Comment: Are you running an old version of Chrome? Do you need to be? Does the problem persist in newer versions?

Comment: Cant re create it in Safari, going to try to update Chrome. Thanks